# Timestamp outgoing packets

Tags: c, linux, timestamp, raw-sockets

I'm trying to get accurate timestamps for outgoing packets (sent using raw sockets). According to [`Linux/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt`](http://os1a.cs.columbia.edu/lxr/source/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt?a=x86), "For send time stamps the outgoing packet is looped back to the socket's error queue with the send time stamp(s) attached. It can be received with recvmsg(flags=MSG_ERRQUEUE).".

Unfortunately, `recvmsg` is always returning `-1` when called on a raw socket (created with `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)` and with `SO_TIMESTAMP` set to `1` with `setsockopt`). What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of getting an accurate timestamp for an outgoing packet?

**Addendum (information):**

I also tried getting the timestamp from a packet sent through an UDP socket (source code below) and `recvmsg` returns `-1`: the error is "Resource temporarily unavailable" (`EAGAIN`).

**Addendum (source code):**

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/net_tstamp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

void die(char* s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* destination_ip = "10.0.0.1";
    int destination_port = 1234;

    int sock;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) {
        die("socket()");
    }

    int timestamp_flags = SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING, &timestamp_flags, sizeof(timestamp_flags)) < 0) {
        die("setsockopt()");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in si_server;
    memset(&si_server, 0, sizeof(si_server));
    si_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_server.sin_port = htons(destination_port);
    if (inet_aton(destination_ip, &si_server.sin_addr) == 0) {
        die("inet_aton()");
    }

    const int buffer_len = 256;
    char buffer[buffer_len];

    const int n_packets = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_packets; ++i) {
        sprintf(buffer, "Packet %d", i);
        if (sendto(sock, buffer, buffer_len, 0, (const sockaddr*) &si_server, sizeof(si_server)) < 0) {
            die("sendto()");
        }

        // Obtain the sent packet timestamp.
        char data[256];
        struct msghdr msg;
        struct iovec entry;
        struct sockaddr_in from_addr;
        struct {
            struct cmsghdr cm;
            char control[512];
        } control;
        int res;

        memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
        msg.msg_iov = &entry;
        msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
        entry.iov_base = data;
        entry.iov_len = sizeof(data);
        msg.msg_name = (caddr_t)&from_addr;
        msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(from_addr);
        msg.msg_control = &control;
        msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(control);        
        if (recvmsg(sock, &msg, MSG_ERRQUEUE) < 0) {
            die("recvmsg()");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you will get different timing if you use SOCK_STREAM?

Comment: btw I use setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int)); to disable Nagel's algorithm. I think you should do that as well. But I'm wondering if you can use two setsockopt in a row?

Comment: apparently you can also add the sockopt at any level you want, to get real timing I guess you would set SO_TIMESTAMP at the IPPROTO_RAW level

Comment: Isn't reading from the error queue non-blocking?  I'm guessing you're getting EAGAIN because the timestamp isn't ready when you're calling recvmsg().  Perhaps try using poll() and wait for POLLERR.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking into the Linux kernel source code, I found that the function responsible for putting the message containing the timestamp of the packet on the error queue is `skb_tx_timestamp`. This function is supposed to be called by the NIC driver and unfortunately, the `e1000` driver doesn't call it (there's a similar function for hardware timestamping, but this is obviously dependent on the NIC driver supporting it).

According to [this NetDev discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network/171376) from last September, "no driver calls skb_tx_timestamp()" and "You'll need to tweak your NIC driver to play with this TX timestamps". After adding a call to `skb_tx_timestamp` to `e1000_xmit_frame` on `e1000_main.c`, I was able to obtain timestamps for outgoing packets (through an UDP socket). I wasn't able to obtain timestamps for outgoing packets on a RAW socket, though (I still get `EAGAIN`).

Comment: This is much better in 2023, chances are your NIC's driver *will* call skb_tx_timestamp() nowadays, at least a grep -r for skb_tx_timestamp in drivers/net returns a truckload of drivers calling it...

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to know what you are doing wrong, since we cannot see your code.

However:
The documentation says that `SO_TIMESTAMP` is for incoming packets, while `SO_TIMESTAMPING` is for outgoing packets.

The kernel documentation contains a full example which you could use as a base - though it's using UDP, but you should be able to adjust it to using a RAW socket.
See the linux kernel [Documentation/networking/timestamping/timestamping.c](http://os1a.cs.columbia.edu/lxr/source/Documentation/networking/timestamping/timestamping.c)

EDIT: It seems transmit timestamping isn't universally supported, see e.g. [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network/171376). Even today just a handful of nic drivers implement software support, and a few have hardware support.

Comment: My bad, I added the source code (trying to get the timestamp from  UDP first). And yes, my code is based on timestamping.c. However, it still doesn't work (`recvmsg` tells me "Resource temporarily unavailable").

Comment: That sounds like EAGAIN, which means there's nothing in the error queue (yet). So you'll have to re-try the recvmsg , or use select()/poll() to get notified when something's there. recvmsg with the MSG_ERRQUEUE flag does not block until something arrives. But see my last EDIT.

Comment: I just saw your last edit - please see my own response :). We both found the same, but I still have a problem: it doesn't seem to work with RAW sockets. Any idea why?

Comment: Well, with the current code, it's just luck of you don't get EAGAIN, so at least make sure you do what I said in the last comment. Also, try to verify that your raw packet actually makes it onto the wire, e.g. debug it with wireshark.

Comment: You're right, I got lucky :). I started getting `EAGAIN` with the UDP socket (but `select` made it go away). As for the raw packet, `select` blocks (not using a timeout) and yes, the raw packet makes it into the wire (tcpdump shows them, and I also get the responses).

Comment: I get strange behaviour with basically the above code - I am only returned a timestamp if the packet successfully arrives at its destination and only once the icmp response is received.  This is contrary to the docs - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt - at line 326.

Comment: Nevermind - SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE is not enabled on this kernel.  I assume the transmit timestamp enabled kernels/drviers deal with the loopback error queue issue, explains why the select() was only unblocking when the ICMP response was received.  Hope this can be of some use to someone somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

sock_tx_timestamp is only called for SOCK_DGRAM sockets in current kernel code.

BTW, the document Documentation/networking/timestamping/timestamping.c isn't very accurate.

SO_TIMESTAMP / SO_TIMESTAMPNS / SO_TIMESTAMPING / SIOCGSTAMP / SIOCGSTAMPNS are similar. Anyone of them will enable application getting the timestamp of a received packet.

With SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE, any one of the above flags will also provide the application a CMSG in MSG_ERRQUEUE, indicating the timestamp of a sent packet.

But SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE is useless at all. It can not even be used to disable the reporting of timestamp of received packets.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to mention the timestamping flag as

```
int timestamp_flags |= SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE;
timestamp_flags |= SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE;
```

And also you have to check the strerror for all system call before getting the data from the msg queue error. This will help you to get rid off of the EAGAIN message.