# Linux, UDP datagrams, and kernel timestamps: Lots of examples and stackoversflow entries later, and still cannot get timestamps at all

Tags: c, linux, sockets, timestamp, udp

I have been trying and failing to get Linux (kernel 4.1.4) to give me timestamps for when UDP datagrams are sent and received.  I have read the original kernel docs (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt), along with lots of examples and a number of stackoverflow entries.  I can send datagrams between sender and receiver with no problems.  But I cannot get timestamps for sending or receiving datagrams, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

One bizarre thing is that when I use the MSG_ERRQUEUE channel for getting timestamp info on a sent datagram, I do get the original outgoing packet, and I do get the first ancillary message (SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR), but I do not get a second message (which should be level SOL_SOCKET, type SCM_TIMESTAMPING).

In another stackoverflow entry on getting timestamps for sent packets ([Timestamp outgoing packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731445/timestamp-outgoing-packets)), someone mentioned that some drivers might not implement the call to `skb_tx_timestamp`, but I checked mine (Realtek), and that call is definitely in there.

Here's how I set up the UDP receiver (error handling code not shown):

```
inf->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

timestampOn = SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE;
r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING, &timestampOn, sizeof(timestampOn));

r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &on, sizeof(on));

memset(&(inf->local), 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
inf->local.sin_family = AF_INET;
inf->local.sin_port = htons(port);
inf->local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

r = bind(inf->fd, (struct sockaddr *)&(inf->local), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

Using SO_REUSEPORT or not doesn't seem to matter.

For receiving, my understanding is that we don't use MSG_ERRQUEUE.  That's only if we want timestamps for sent messages.  Besides, when I use MSG_ERRQUEUE with recvmsg, I get "resource temporarily unavailable."  Here's how I receive datagrams:

```
int recv_len;
struct msghdr   msg;
struct iovec    iov;

memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

// Space for control message info plus timestamp
char ctrl[2048];
memset(ctrl, 0, sizeof(ctrl));
//struct cmsghdr *cmsg = (struct cmsghdr *) &ctrl;

// Ancillary data buffer and length
msg.msg_control      = (char *) ctrl;
msg.msg_controllen   = sizeof(ctrl);

// Dest address info
msg.msg_name         = (struct sockaddr *) &(inf->remote);
msg.msg_namelen      = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

// Array of data buffers (scatter/gather)
msg.msg_iov          = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen       = 1;

// Data buffer pointer and length
iov.iov_base         = buf;
iov.iov_len          = len;

recv_len = recvmsg(inf->fd, &msg, 0);
```

And then I pass a pointer to msg to another function (`handle_time`) that does this:

```
struct timespec* ts = NULL;
struct cmsghdr* cmsg;
struct sock_extended_err *ext;

for( cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(msg); cmsg; cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(msg,cmsg) ) {
    printf("level=%d, type=%d, len=%zu\n", cmsg->cmsg_level, cmsg->cmsg_type, cmsg->cmsg_len);
}
```

**Zero messages are received.**  So that's the first problem.  My setup code above matches like half a dozen other examples I've found on the web, but I'm getting no ancillary data from this.

Next, let's turn to sending datagrams.  Here's the setup:

```
inf->port = port;
inf->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

memset(&(inf->remote), 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
inf->remote.sin_family = AF_INET;
inf->remote.sin_port = htons(port);

timestampOn = SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE;
r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING, &timestampOn, sizeof(timestampOn));

on = 1;
r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &on, sizeof(on));

r = inet_aton(address, &(inf->remote.sin_addr));
```

And this is how I send a datagram:

```
int send_len, r, i;
struct msghdr   msg;
struct iovec    iov;

memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

// Space for control message info plus timestamp
char ctrl[2048];
memset(ctrl, 0, sizeof(ctrl));
//struct cmsghdr *cmsg = (struct cmsghdr *) &ctrl;

// Ancillary data buffer and length
//msg.msg_control      = (char *) ctrl;
//msg.msg_controllen   = sizeof(ctrl);    

// Dest address info
msg.msg_name         = (struct sockaddr *) &(inf->remote);
msg.msg_namelen      = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

// Array of data buffers (scatter/gather)
msg.msg_iov          = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen       = 1;

// Data buffer pointer and length
iov.iov_base         = buf;
iov.iov_len          = len;

send_len = sendmsg(inf->fd, &msg, 0);
```

Examples I've seen reuse the msg and iov data structures, but in my experimentation, I added code to make sure things were cleared, just in case the send left anything behind, although it didn't make any difference.  Here's the code for getting the timestamp:

```
memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));
memset(ctrl, 0, sizeof(ctrl));
msg.msg_control      = (char *) ctrl;
msg.msg_controllen   = sizeof(ctrl);
msg.msg_name         = (struct sockaddr *) &(inf->remote);
msg.msg_namelen      = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
msg.msg_iov          = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen       = 1;
iov.iov_base         = junk_buf;
iov.iov_len          = sizeof(junk_buf);

for (;;) {
    r = recvmsg(inf->fd, &msg, MSG_ERRQUEUE);
    if (r<0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Didn't get kernel time\n");
        return send_len;
    }

    printf("recvmsg returned %d\n", r);
    handle_time(&msg);
}
```

The data buffer contains the original datagram as expected.  The ancillary data I get back includes a single message, which handle_time prints as:

```
level=0, type=11, len=48
```

This is level SOL_IP and type IP_RECVERR, which is expected according to the docs.  Looking into the payload (a struct sock_extended_err), the errno is 42 (ENOMSG, No message of desired type) and origin is 4 (SO_EE_ORIGIN_TXSTATUS).  From the docs, this is supposed to happen and demonstrates that in fact I did manage to inform the kernel that I want TX status messages.  But there is no second ancillary message!

I have tried to see if there is any kernel compile option that might disable this, but I haven't found any.  So I'm just completely baffled here.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**  I tried running this same code on another Linux machine, this time CentOS 7 (kernel 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64).  I can't figure out what what kind of NIC that machine has, but when I try to send datagrams, I get some other weird behavior.  For the very first datagram, when I start this program, I get back the message and a single ancillary message, just as above.  For every subsequent `sendmsg` call, errno tells me that I get an "Invalid argument" error.  This error goes away if I don't enable timestamps on the socket.

**UPDATE 2:**  I discovered that I had not been making an ioctl necessary to enable timestamps in the driver.  Unfortunately, when I do this call, I get ENODEV from errno (no such device).  Here's how I'm trying to do it (which I'm imitating from https://github.com/majek/openonload/blob/master/src/tests/onload/hwtimestamping/tx_timestamping.c):

```
struct ifreq ifr;
struct hwtstamp_config hwc;

inf->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
hwc.flags = 0;
hwc.tx_type = HWTSTAMP_TX_ON;
hwc.rx_filter = HWTSTAMP_FILTER_ALL;
ifr.ifr_data = (char*)&hwc;
r = ioctl(inf->fd, SIOCSHWTSTAMP, &ifr);
```

That being said, I'd be relatively happy with software timestamps, which should not need this call.  So I'm not sure this is helpful anyhow.

**UPDATE 3:**  A compilable example was requested.  The whole program is pretty minimal, so I put it into pastebin here:  https://pastebin.com/qd0gspRc

Also, here's the output from ethtool:

```
Time stamping parameters for eth0:
Capabilities:
        software-transmit     (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE)
        software-receive      (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE)
        software-system-clock (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE)
PTP Hardware Clock: none
Hardware Transmit Timestamp Modes: none
Hardware Receive Filter Modes: none
```

Since this obviously doesn't support hardware timestamps, the ioctl is moot.  I tried changing the SO_TIMESTAMPING setting to SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE and SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE for sender and receiver.  That didn't help.

Then I tried adding SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE to both.  I finally started getting something:

```
level=1, type=37, len=64
```

Level 1 is SOL_SOCKET, and type 37 is SCM_TIMESTAMPING.  I'll go back to the docs and figure out how to interpret this.  It says something about passing an array of three time structures.  The driver's call to `skb_tx_timestamp` should have been sufficient so that it wouldn't require that I enable "fake" software timestamps to get something out.

Comment: In your "Update 2", you need to at least fill in `ifr.ifr_name` with the actual device name (e.g. "eth0").  You should probably also check what kinds of timestamping your network card/driver supports, run the command `ethtool -T   eth0`

Comment: Sorry, but your question can't be answer in this sate you have not give, a [mcve], we can't verify that your code is not wrong (that include error handling), so I vote to close your question for the lack of [mcve].

Comment: as a guess I will try to add `SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE` and `SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE` to the bit field `timestampOn = SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE;` and `timestampOn = SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE;`

Comment: the posted code snippets do not compile, so we cannot reproduce the problem.  Please post a [mcve] for the UDP sender and a second one for the UDP receiver.  Otherwise, we are unlikely to be able to help you.

Comment: Here is the compilable version:  https://pastebin.com/qd0gspRc

Comment: "I'll go back to the docs and figure out how to interpret this.", I thing that you should read "2.1 SCM_TIMESTAMPING records" of https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like I say in comment the use of `SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE` and `SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE` is necessary because if I understand correctly [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt), some bits are to generate the timestamp and some bits are here to report them in control message:

> 1.3.1 Timestamp Generation
>
> Some bits are requests to the stack to try to generate timestamps. Any
>   combination of them is valid. Changes to these bits apply to newly
>   created packets, not to packets already in the stack. As a result, it
>   is possible to selectively request timestamps for a subset of packets
>   (e.g., for sampling) by embedding an `send()` call within two `setsockopt`
>   calls, one to enable timestamp generation and one to disable it.
>   Timestamps may also be generated for reasons other than being
>   requested by a particular socket, such as when receive timestamping is
>   enabled system wide, as explained earlier.
>
> 1.3.2 Timestamp Reporting
>
> The other three bits control which timestamps will be reported in a
>   generated control message. Changes to the bits take immediate effect
>   at the timestamp reporting locations in the stack. Timestamps are only
>   reported for packets that also have the relevant timestamp generation
>   request set.

After, to use the data documentation say:

> 2.1 `SCM_TIMESTAMPING` records
>
> These timestamps are returned in a control message with cmsg_level
>   `SOL_SOCKET`, cmsg_type `SCM_TIMESTAMPING`, and payload of type
>
> `struct scm_timestamping {    struct timespec ts[3]; };`
>
> ...
>
> The structure can return up to three timestamps. This is a legacy
>   feature. At least one field is non-zero at any time. Most timestamps
>   are passed in `ts[0]`. Hardware timestamps are passed in `ts[2]`.

To get transmit timestamp this require some configuration, first you need to know [that software timestamp are not always available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747460/7076153), I only achieve to get hardware transmit timestamp. But I'm not an expert in these domain, I just try to implemented timestamp with information that I found.

Secondly, I needed to activate hardware feature with [linuxptp tool](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/), I use [hwstamp_cli](https://www.mankier.com/8/hwstamp_ctl):

```
hwstamp_ctl -i eth0 -r 1 -t 1
```

With this and some modification on your code I achieve to get hardware transmit timestamp but only with ethX interface because lo interface don't have these feature AFAIK so the final code is:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <linux/errqueue.h>
#include <linux/net_tstamp.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define UDP_MAX_LENGTH 1500

typedef struct {
  int fd;
  int port;
  int err_no;
  struct sockaddr_in local;
  struct sockaddr_in remote;
  struct timeval time_kernel;
  struct timeval time_user;
  int64_t prev_serialnum;
} socket_info;

static int setup_udp_receiver(socket_info *inf, int port) {
  inf->port = port;
  inf->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (inf->fd < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: socket failed: %s\n",
            strerror(inf->err_no));
    return inf->fd;
  }

  int timestampOn =
      SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE |
      SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE |
      SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE |
      // SOF_TIMESTAMPING_OPT_TSONLY |
      0;
  int r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING, &timestampOn,
                     sizeof timestampOn);
  if (r < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: setsockopt failed: %s\n",
            strerror(inf->err_no));
    return r;
  }

  int on = 1;
  r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &on, sizeof on);
  if (r < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: setsockopt2 failed: %s\n",
            strerror(inf->err_no));
    return r;
  }

  inf->local = (struct sockaddr_in){.sin_family = AF_INET,
                                    .sin_port = htons((uint16_t)port),
                                    .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)};
  r = bind(inf->fd, (struct sockaddr *)&inf->local, sizeof inf->local);
  if (r < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: bind failed: %s\n",
            strerror(inf->err_no));
    return r;
  }

  inf->prev_serialnum = -1;

  return 0;
}

static int setup_udp_sender(socket_info *inf, int port, char *address) {
  inf->port = port;
  inf->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (inf->fd < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_client: socket failed: %s\n",
            strerror(inf->err_no));
    return inf->fd;
  }

  int timestampOn =
      SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE |
      SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE |
      SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE |
      // SOF_TIMESTAMPING_OPT_TSONLY |
      0;
  int r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING, &timestampOn,
                     sizeof timestampOn);
  if (r < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: setsockopt failed: %s\n",
            strerror(inf->err_no));
    return r;
  }

  inf->remote = (struct sockaddr_in){.sin_family = AF_INET,
                                     .sin_port = htons((uint16_t)port)};
  r = inet_aton(address, &inf->remote.sin_addr);
  if (r == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_client: inet_aton failed\n");
    inf->err_no = 0;
    return -1;
  }

  inf->local = (struct sockaddr_in){.sin_family = AF_INET,
                                    .sin_port = htons(0),
                                    .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)};
  inf->prev_serialnum = -1;

  return 0;
}

static void handle_scm_timestamping(struct scm_timestamping *ts) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof ts->ts / sizeof *ts->ts; i++) {
    printf("timestamp: %lld.%.9lds\n", (long long)ts->ts[i].tv_sec,
           ts->ts[i].tv_nsec);
  }
}

static void handle_time(struct msghdr *msg) {

  for (struct cmsghdr *cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(msg); cmsg;
       cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(msg, cmsg)) {
    printf("level=%d, type=%d, len=%zu\n", cmsg->cmsg_level, cmsg->cmsg_type,
           cmsg->cmsg_len);

    if (cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_IP && cmsg->cmsg_type == IP_RECVERR) {
      struct sock_extended_err *ext =
          (struct sock_extended_err *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
      printf("errno=%d, origin=%d\n", ext->ee_errno, ext->ee_origin);
      continue;
    }

    if (cmsg->cmsg_level != SOL_SOCKET)
      continue;

    switch (cmsg->cmsg_type) {
    case SO_TIMESTAMPNS: {
      struct scm_timestamping *ts = (struct scm_timestamping *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
      handle_scm_timestamping(ts);
    } break;
    case SO_TIMESTAMPING: {
      struct scm_timestamping *ts = (struct scm_timestamping *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
      handle_scm_timestamping(ts);
    } break;
    default:
      /* Ignore other cmsg options */
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("End messages\n");
}

static ssize_t udp_receive(socket_info *inf, char *buf, size_t len) {
  char ctrl[2048];
  struct iovec iov = (struct iovec){.iov_base = buf, .iov_len = len};
  struct msghdr msg = (struct msghdr){.msg_control = ctrl,
                                      .msg_controllen = sizeof ctrl,
                                      .msg_name = &inf->remote,
                                      .msg_namelen = sizeof inf->remote,
                                      .msg_iov = &iov,
                                      .msg_iovlen = 1};
  ssize_t recv_len = recvmsg(inf->fd, &msg, 0);
  gettimeofday(&inf->time_user, NULL);

  if (recv_len < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "udp_receive: recvfrom failed: %s\n",
            strerror(inf->err_no));
  }

  handle_time(&msg);

  return recv_len;
}

static ssize_t udp_send(socket_info *inf, char *buf, size_t len) {
  struct iovec iov = (struct iovec){.iov_base = buf, .iov_len = len};
  struct msghdr msg = (struct msghdr){.msg_name = &inf->remote,
                                      .msg_namelen = sizeof inf->remote,
                                      .msg_iov = &iov,
                                      .msg_iovlen = 1};
  gettimeofday(&inf->time_user, NULL);
  ssize_t send_len = sendmsg(inf->fd, &msg, 0);
  if (send_len < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "udp_send: sendmsg failed: %s\n", strerror(inf->err_no));
  }

  return send_len;
}

static ssize_t meq_receive(socket_info *inf, char *buf, size_t len) {
  struct iovec iov = (struct iovec){.iov_base = buf, .iov_len = len};
  char ctrl[2048];
  struct msghdr msg = (struct msghdr){.msg_control = ctrl,
                                      .msg_controllen = sizeof ctrl,
                                      .msg_name = &inf->remote,
                                      .msg_namelen = sizeof inf->remote,
                                      .msg_iov = &iov,
                                      .msg_iovlen = 1};
  ssize_t recv_len = recvmsg(inf->fd, &msg, MSG_ERRQUEUE);
  if (recv_len < 0) {
    inf->err_no = errno;
    if (errno != EAGAIN) {
      fprintf(stderr, "meq_receive: recvmsg failed: %s\n",
              strerror(inf->err_no));
    }
    return recv_len;
  }
  handle_time(&msg);

  return recv_len;
}

typedef struct {
  int64_t serialnum;

  int64_t user_time_serialnum;
  int64_t user_time;

  int64_t kernel_time_serialnum;
  int64_t kernel_time;

  size_t message_bytes;
} message_header;

static const size_t payload_max = UDP_MAX_LENGTH - sizeof(message_header);

static ssize_t generate_random_message(socket_info *inf, char *buf,
                                       size_t len) {
  if (len < sizeof(message_header)) {
    return -1;
  }
  message_header *header = (message_header *)buf;
  char *payload = (char *)(header + 1);
  size_t payload_len = (size_t)random() % (payload_max + 1);
  if (payload_len > len - sizeof(message_header)) {
    payload_len = len - sizeof(message_header);
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < payload_len; i++) {
    payload[i] = (char)random();
  }

  static int64_t serial_num = 0;
  *header = (message_header){
      .user_time_serialnum = inf->prev_serialnum,
      .user_time = inf->time_user.tv_sec * 1000000000L + inf->time_user.tv_usec,
      .kernel_time_serialnum = inf->prev_serialnum,
      .kernel_time =
          inf->time_kernel.tv_sec * 1000000000L + inf->time_kernel.tv_usec,
      .serialnum = serial_num,
      .message_bytes = payload_len};
  size_t total = payload_len + sizeof *header;

  printf("uts%5" PRId64 ": kt=%" PRId64 ", ut=%" PRId64 ", sn=%" PRId64
         ": s=%zu\n",
         header->user_time_serialnum, header->kernel_time, header->user_time,
         header->serialnum, total);

  inf->prev_serialnum = serial_num++;

  return (ssize_t)total;
}

static void sender_loop(char *host) {
  socket_info inf;
  int ret = setup_udp_sender(&inf, 8000, host);
  if (ret < 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    useconds_t t = random() % 2000000;
    usleep(t);
    char packet_buffer[4096];
    ssize_t len =
        generate_random_message(&inf, packet_buffer, sizeof packet_buffer);
    if (len < 0) {
      return;
    }
    udp_send(&inf, packet_buffer, (size_t)len);
    while (meq_receive(&inf, packet_buffer, sizeof packet_buffer) != -1) {
    }
  }
}

static void receiver_loop(void) {
  socket_info inf;
  int ret = setup_udp_receiver(&inf, 8000);
  if (ret < 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    char packet_buffer[4096];
    udp_receive(&inf, packet_buffer, sizeof packet_buffer);
  }
}

#define USAGE "Usage: %s [-r | -s host]\n"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, USAGE, argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  if (0 == strcmp(argv[1], "-s")) {
    if (argc < 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, USAGE, argv[0]);
      return 0;
    }
    sender_loop(argv[2]);
  } else if (0 == strcmp(argv[1], "-r")) {
    receiver_loop();
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, USAGE, argv[0]);
  }
}
```

Exemple output:

```
$ ./a.out -r
level=1, type=37, len=64
timestamp: 1511196758.087209387s
timestamp: 0.000000000s
timestamp: 0.000000000s
End messages
level=1, type=37, len=64
timestamp: 1511196759.333507671s
timestamp: 0.000000000s
timestamp: 0.000000000s
End messages
$ ./a.out -s "8.8.8.8"
uts   -1: kt=238059712, ut=140918979990070, sn=0: s=482
uts    0: kt=238059712, ut=1511197522000237457, sn=1: s=132
level=1, type=37, len=64
timestamp: 0.000000000s
timestamp: 0.000000000s
timestamp: 1511197359.637050597s
level=0, type=11, len=48
errno=42, origin=4
End messages
uts    1: kt=238059712, ut=1511197523000483805, sn=2: s=1454
level=1, type=37, len=64
timestamp: 0.000000000s
timestamp: 0.000000000s
timestamp: 1511197360.883295397s
level=0, type=11, len=48
errno=42, origin=4
End messages
```

Live test: [sender](http://rextester.com/ZCI27564), [receiver](http://rextester.com/NPZT9983)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to produce this working example.  Some things are definitely improved!  I am still having a few problems with it, though.  Your sending function omits the code necessary to get the TX timestamp, so I added it back in.  Unfortunately, I get nothing at all back from recvmsg on MSG_ERRQUEUE, not even the original datagram that was sent.  I've tried changing the options for SO_TIMESTAMPING, but nothing.  I used to get *something* back from MSG_ERRQUEUE, so I don't know what's changed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this.  I copied and pasted your exact code, but I'm still getting some odd behaviors.  If I send to "127.0.0.1", then the recvmsg from MSG_ERRQUEUE always comes back with EAGAIN.  If I provide the address of another machine, the first datagram gets a message from the error channel where only ts[0] is nonzero.  But after that, ALL subsequent recvmsg from MSG_ERRQUEUE come back with EAGAIN.  Each run, the sending kernel timestamp is different, but I can't figure out why it won't let met get a kernel timestamp for more than one datagram sent per run.

Comment: I figured out why recvmsg from MSG_ERRQUEUE is only working the first time.  It's because *every* subsequent call to sendmsg fails with EINVAL.  The first one always succeeds, and I get a timestamp.  Then something breaks or I'm failing to take some important action.  So then I tried closing and reopening the socket for every transmission, and it works!  But why do I have to open the socket fresh for every datagram?

Comment: One more observation.  Leaving everything else the same (i.e. same socket options, etc.), I don't have to keep closing and reopening the socket if I simply don't do the recvmsg on MSG_ERRQUEUE.  So doing a single recvmsg on MSG_ERRQUEUE trashes the socket somehow.

Comment: I tried various combinations SO_TIMESTAMPING flags for the sender.  Removing RX flags did nothing.  Any combo that doesn't include SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE is able to send any number of datagrams, but the recvmsg from MSG_ERRQUEUE always comes up empty (that returns EAGAIN).  Any combo *with* SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE is able to get back a timestamp for the *first* datagram sent, but after that all calls to sendmsg fail with EINVAL.