# Linux HW packet Timestamping unexpected jitter

Tags: linux, sockets, timestamping

I used the code proposed by Stargateur in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313383/linux-udp-datagrams-and-kernel-timestamps-lots-of-examples-and-stackoversflow/47329376#47329376) that works very well (thanks !!!)

I used it to compare tx timestamping from NIC1 to rx timestamping from NIC2 on another machine, both being directly linked with 1 meter cable.
I expected to have a difference between both timestamps close to a constant (corresponding to clocks difference + time travel throutgh the NIC and the cable).

However I got an enormeous jitter (several 100s of ms of variation between timestamps differences) between measurements.

Any idea on what is going wrong ?

Thanks